# How to add specific git commit on top of old commit state

Tags: git

I'm debugging at some old git commit level, and I want to add on top of that some specific recent commit, like that:

A->B->C->D->...->E->....->Latest

could be much more than that, this example is only for illustration

I'm now working at "C" and I want to have "E" on top of that, so that I will be at:

A->B->C->E

How can I do it? (pick single commit on top of old commit point)

Comment: `git rebase -i HEAD~N`?

Comment: For a single commit : `git cherry-pick E`

Comment: Thanks for all, LeGEC's answer helped me

Answer (score 0):

As @LeGEC commented: the way is to `git cherry-pick E`